# $(TZ=MSZ+24 date +"%d%m%Y") not working as expected during daylight savings?

Tags: bash, date, unix, timezone, aix

I have a script that makes use of `$(TZ=MSZ+24 date +"%d%m%Y")`to get yesterday's date in BASH (AIX system). So far it's worked flawlessly for 5 months, until last night, when it didn't worked properly. Usually it runs at 01:00 AM server time, but last night something strange happened, and the only reason it wouldn't have worked is because of  `$(TZ=MSZ+24 date +"%d%m%Y")`.

So, my question is, if Saturday night the clock went forward 1 hour, could it influence `$(TZ=MSZ+24 date +"%d%m%Y")` so when it ran on Sunday, it would have given a strange result ?

Thank you

Comment: In European Union, switch to Summer Time actually happened on Sunday.

Comment: "it didn't work properly" and "something strange happened"  - that's not very descriptive.  What happened?  What result did you get?  Which time zone are you in anyway?

Comment: Hi, it did not work properly as in it didn't return the expected value. I don't know what it actually returned, because I don't have set -x in that script. How do I know that that statement didn't work as expected?  It's because in the script there is an if statement based on  the above mentioned doing some calculations. It didn't reach that part, because no calculations were done.

Comment: I've looked at several timezone abbreviation sources on the web, and MSZ is not listed on any of them.  Are you sure it is valid?

Comment: Check the `zdump` utility.  If you give an invalid timezone then most utilities default to UTC (GMT).  The exact time of the change varies, see http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/events.html

Comment: Hi,  "The suggestion has been made that MSZ is a widely(?) employed alias (in some region(s) of the Gernan
speaking world?) for MESZ that is standardly defined for "Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit" (GMT+0200); " . Also after a deeper search in the logs, it was this. The date returned was 26.03.2016, instead of 27.03.2016. I don't know how to get around this for future time changes :(

Comment: Don't abuse TZ; install GNU-dateutils and use `/opt/freeware/bin/date -d yesterday`

Comment: Unfortunately, installing anything is not an option

Comment: The chosen abbreviation is irrelevant.  This is a POSIX formatted time zone, which is 12 hours behind UTC (aka, UTC-12).  See [this doc](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-posix/).   The only issue here is that perhaps your local time zone wasn't quite where you thought it was in relation to UTC.  Since you still haven't told us what location or time zone *you* are in, it's impossible to answer.  (The [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) also has information on POSIX time zones, near the bottom.)

Comment: Hello Matt, it's basically CET (central European time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the daylight saving time, 24 hours ago can be today or the day before yesterday. When you want to change your script without using the GNU-date, use the following trick:

You are sure that yesterday is 20 or 30 hours ago. Which one? Well, the most recent one that is not today.

```
echo "$(TZ=MSZ+30 date +"%d%m%Y")
$(TZ=MSZ+20 date +"%d%m%Y")" | grep -v "$(date +"%d%m%Y")" | tail -1
```