# Crontab using yesterday date

Tags: date, unix, cron

I'm using old version of Unix and i want to run script everyday using yesterday date
My script lets say

30 08 * * * script.ksh dd mm yy
How to make it

Comment: You can find yesterday with a non-GNU `date` with https://stackoverflow.com/a/36391308/3220113 (also considering Daylight Saving Time)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
script.ksh $(date -d yesterday "+\%d \%m \%y")
```

`%` is quoted because that is a new-line symbol in a crontab.

Comment: This old version doesn't support date -d yesterday

Comment: @SamerEssam Try `date -d "-1 day"`, may be you need to use locale-specific names.